# ¿Cómo obtener el trafico de red de un dispositivo conectado a mi red local con Node js?

Tags: nodejs

Quisiera saber si existe alguna librería de nodejs con la que pueda obtener el trafico de una lista de IP conectados a mi red local.

He intentado con el protocolo SNMP usando esta librería [net-snmp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/net-snmp), pero tiene limitaciones y he tenido problemas para extraer la información, ¿existe algún otro modo de obtener esta información?

```
var options = {
              port: 9002,
              retries: 1,
              timeout: 100000,
              version: snmp.Version1,
              idBitsSize: 16
            };

          var session = snmp.createSession ("192.168.0.56", "public",options);

//cada oid me permite obtener información como marca, nivel de batería, etc 
oids = ["1.3.6.1.4.1.28018.1.10.6.0","1.3.6.1.4.1.28018.1.10.12.0"];

              session.get (oids, function (error, varbinds) {
                if (error) {
                  console.error (error);
                } else {
                  for (var i = 0; i < varbinds.length; i++)
                    if (snmp.isVarbindError (varbinds[i])){
                      console.error (snmp.varbindError (varbinds[i]));
                    }
                    else{
                      console.log (varbinds[i].oid + " = " + varbinds[i].value);
                    }

                }
              });

              session.trap (snmp.TrapType.LinkDown, function (error) {
                if (error)
                  console.error (error);
              });
```

El problema radica en que el protocolo SNMP tan solo me permite obtener información pública del dispositivo, pero la información del trafico, ruido, etc, se encuentra de manera privada y no puedo acceder.

Comment: Hola Kevin. Pedir maneras de hacerlo es muy amplia y tambien basada en opiniones. Te sugiero que lo hables en el [chat] y que alguien pueda orientarte. Una vez que ya estés desarrollando , si tienes errores o problemas concretos puedes preguntar aqui tus dudas siguiendo [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo

Comment: La pregunta es interesante, si dices que ya haz hecho usa de una librería, ¿por qué no colocar el ejemplo de lo que llevas? ¿qué información logras recopilar? ¿qué información sientes que te hace falta? etc

Comment: @Jorius ok, voy a agregar la información.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Quisiera saber si existe alguna librería de nodejs con la que pueda
>   obtener el trafico de una lista de IP conectados a mi red local.

Cuando tu utitlizas el protocolo SNMP tienes un target al que apuntas, este target es una ip de por sí, por lo que la el protocolo SNMP carece de utilidad si lo que necesitas es listar las ips de tu red.

De todos modos si quisieras obteners las ips de las interfaces de red puedes usar la función [os.networkInterfaces()](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_networkinterfaces) de la librería estándar `OS` de node.js

---

> El problema radica en que el protocolo SNMP tan solo me permite
>   obtener información pública del dispositivo, pero la información del
>   trafico, ruido, etc, se encuentra de manera privada y no puedo
>   acceder.

La librería que estás usando ya te permite acceder a esta información, ésta usa el protocolo SNMP como indica su nombre, tan sólo tienes que averiguar que oids utilizar, te recomiendo usar un software como [iReasoning MIB Browser](http://ireasoning.com/mibbrowser.shtml) para poder ver que oids necesitas.

En todo caso te dejo una lista de los que podrías usar:

- **ifDescr**: Una descripción de la interfaz provista por el usuario
- **ifType**: El tipo de la interfaz (Ethernet, Wireless, etc)
- **ifOperStatus**: Si la interfaz está levantada, caída o en algún modo de prueba
- **ifMtu**: El tamaño del paquete más largo que puede ser enviado por la interfaz
- **ifSpeed**: El ancho de banda máximo de la interfaz
- **ifPhysAddress**: La dirección física de tu interfaz
- **ifInOctets**: El número de octetos recibidos por la interfaz
- **ifOutOctets**: El número de octetos enviados por la interfaz

**interfaz** hace referencia a la interfaz de red, para encontrar la interfaz que está activa usa el siguiente oid, **ifNumber:** `1.3.6.1.2.1.2.1.0`, que identifica el número de la interfaz que estas usando, luego para acceder a **ifDescr**, por ejemplo usas ese identificador.

**Ejm:**

**ifNumber:** `1.3.6.1.2.1.2.1.0` = **8**

=> **ifDescr:** `.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.8`= wlan0

---

Puedes leer un poco más en estos enlaces:

https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6762/measurement-of-traffic-parameters-using-snmp?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/snmp/appa_01.htm